How to use Vue3 components in Vue2 project?
I have a Vue2+JS project that I want to add a chat component to, but I found some open source projects that were written using Vue3+ts. How should I use the components developed by Vue3 in My Project?
I have browsed use-vue-3-compiled-build-into-vue-2-project question, but I really don't want to migrage my vue2 project to vue3.

"I really don't want to migrage my vue2 project to vue3." but Vue 2 is EoL, you shouldn't be using it anymore: https://v2.vuejs.org/eol/

Unfortunately, if the library does not have a version for vue 2 a simple adaptation will not work. To integrate this library you will need to bring them to a common denominator.
This is either to create a fork where you plug in vue-demi as a dependency and eliminate any reactivity issues that may arise.
Or as @gertvdijk wrote above you need to upgrade the project to vue 3, either in parts or completely, because further it will be more and more difficult to maintain it.
Or alternatively consider other libraries that support vue 2 but may contain vulnerabilities.
